# Parse and Facebook Authentication

Tags: objective-c, facebook

When I go to Parse.com and click “Settings” on the top menu then “Authentification” in the left menu. There you can see a “Facebook Application” (please refer to picture below) section. When I type in my App ID and App Secret here it keeps giving me an error saying "Service Unavailable".

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's just a network issue. Just try again.

Comment: Nope still says "Service Unavailable" :(

Comment: Well, you may try this out. So go to your **Facebook dash board** and tinker around **Settings** especially at **Security** (Allow API Access to App Settings -> Yes) and **Client OAuth Settings** (Client OAuth Login, Web OAuth Login -> Yes)

Comment: Yup all all them set to yes.

Comment: Sounds like a known bug (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/739979609469376/). You can try creating a new app and see if that works.